# How do I lookup a multicast queue?

Tags: activemq-artemis

Configured following topic/queue in `broker.xml`:

```xml
<address name="Topic1">
   <multicast>
      <queue name="Queue1"/>
      <queue name="Queue2"/>
   </multicast>
</address>
```

How can I create producer for Queue1/Queue2 for send message? I am using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.6.3.

Using following way I am creating connection factory, connection and queue lookup

```java
Hashtable<String, Object> properties = new Hashtable<>();
properties.put("connectionFactory.ConnectionFactory", (tcp://localhost:61618,tcp://localhost:61616)?ha=true&retryInterval=3000&reconnectAttempts=-1&initialConnectAttempts=10&maxRetryInterval=3000&clientFailureCheckPeriod=1000);
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
InitialContext jndiContext = new InitialContext(properties);
ConnectionFactory connFactory = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup(connectionFactory);
Connection connection = connFactory.createConnection(userName, password);
Session session = connection.createSession(true,javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
//Using following way looking up Multicast Queue2 on Address Topic1
Destination dest = new ActiveMQTopic("Topic1::Queue2");
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(dest);
producer.send(message, Message.DEFAULT_DELIVERY_MODE, Message.DEFAULT_PRIORITY, msgTTL);
```

After did with the above code change and try to send message, message will not send to queue "Queue2"

Comment: I have updated my comment on above question with the example

Comment: Can you clarify why you chose that specific answer as correct? It actually cites my answer and uses Spring JMS which you don't appear to be using. Thanks!

Comment: Wow!
Just crazy!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Same solution as @justin with spring and artemis 2.7.0:

```
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(new 
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616"));
    //this is the important part
    jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("Topic1::Queue2", "hello");
```

Answer (score 2):

In general you want to pick the right kind of routing-type for your needs. The choices are:

- anycast: provides point-to-point semantics (e.g. a JMS queue); messages sent to the address are routed to just **one** anycast queue
- multicast: provides publish-subscribe semantics (e.g. a JMS topic); messages sent to the address are routed to **all** multicast queues

You've got an address named `Topic` with 2 multicast queues - `Queue1` & `Queue2`. Therefore, messages sent to `Topic` will go to both `Queue1` & `Queue2`. If you want to send messages to just one queue you might consider using a different configuration (e.g. an address with an anycast queue).

However, if you find that you really need your existing configuration for whatever reason then you can send message using the fully qualified queue name (i.e. FQQN) via the syntax `<address>::<queue>`. I see that you're already attempting to do this, e.g.:

```
Destination dest = new ActiveMQTopic("Topic1::Queue2");
```

However, the version of ActiveMQ Artemis you're using doesn't support FQQN for producers. To use this functionality I recommend you upgrade to *at least* 2.7.0 or ideally to [the latest release which is 2.17.0](http://activemq.apache.org/artemis/download.html).